# call function after html loaded on new window

Tags: jquery, html

is there any way to run this code `mailTab.alert('Test');` after html loaded without using `window.onload`? Running the code after images/css loaded will take up too much time. I have tried `$(mailTab.document).ready(function () {});`, but it didn't work

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script>
          $('#certform').ajaxForm(function () {
              var mailTab = window.open('private.php?action=send&uid={$thread['uid']}');



              mailTab.alert('Test');


                        });
    </script>
```

EDIT: using `$(document).ready(function () {});` works, but alert shows up before html is loaded

Comment: cant you just use document.ready?

Comment: it shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` on console when I use `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Comment: maybe u didn't add refrence to jquery script files (jquery.js / jquery.min.js)

Comment: think your single quote is messed up. shouldn't it be something like window.open("private.php?action=send&uid={$thread['uid']}");

Comment: It's the same no matter single quote of double quote

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
             mailTab.alert('Test');
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: i'm getting lots of error in console when I add this `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: pls share your console and current snippet

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lpsieu , I'm actually editing template from mybb forum so I don't think I can run the code on snippet

Answer (score 0):

adding `mailTab.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {});` seems to work for me

```
<script>
          $('#certform').ajaxForm(function () {
              var mailTab = window.open('private.php?action=send&uid={$thread['uid']}');


mailTab.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
              mailTab.alert('Test');
});

                        });
    </script>
```